# QuerySolution, keep the "< >"

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I'm currently stuck on my project on creating a Fuseki Triple Store Browser. I need to visualize all the data from a TripleStore and make the app browsable. The only problem is that the QuerySolution leaves out the "< >" that are in the triplestore.

If I use the `ResultSetFormatter.asText(ResultSet)` it returns this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subject                    | predicate                                         | object                                           |
=====================================================================================================================================
| <urn:animals:data>         | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Seq> |
| <urn:animals:data>         | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_1>   | <urn:animals:lion>                               |
| <urn:animals:data>         | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_2>   | <urn:animals:tarantula>                          |
| <urn:animals:data>         | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_3>   | <urn:animals:hippopotamus>                       |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice that the some of the data contains the smaller/greater than signs "<" and ">". As soon as i try to parse the data from the ResultSet, it removes those sign, so that the data looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| subject                  | predicate                                       | object                                         |
===============================================================================================================================
| urn:animals:data         | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#Seq |
| urn:animals:data         | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_1   | urn:animals:lion                               |
| urn:animals:data         | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_2   | urn:animals:tarantula                          |
| urn:animals:data         | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#_3   | urn:animals:hippopotamus                       |
```

As you can see, the data doesn't contain the "<" and ">" signs.

This is how I parse the data from the ResultSet:

```
while (rs.hasNext()) {
            // Moves onto the next result
            QuerySolution sol = rs.next();
            // Return the value of the named variable in this binding.
            // A return of null indicates that the variable is not present in
            // this solution        
            RDFNode object = sol.get("object");
            RDFNode predicate = sol.get("predicate");
            RDFNode subject = sol.get("subject");


            // Fill the table with the data
            DefaultTableModel modelTable = (DefaultTableModel) this.getModel();
            modelTable.addRow(new Object[] { subject, predicate, object });
        }
```

It's quite hard to explain this problem, but is there a way to keep the "< >" signs after parsing the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The '<>' are used by the formatter to indicate that the value is a URI rather than a string: so `"http://example.com/"` is a literal text value, whereas `<http://example.com/>` is a URI.

You can do the same yourself:

```
RDFNode node; // subject, predicate, or object    

if (node.isURIResource()) {
    return "<" + node.asResource().getURI() + ">";
} else {
    ...
}
```

But it's much easier to use [FmtUtils](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/util/FmtUtils.html):

```
String nodeAsString = FmtUtils.stringForRDFNode(subject); // or predicate, or object
```

What you need to do is get that code invoked when the table cell is rendered: currently the table is using `Object::toString()`.

In outline, the steps needed are:

```
modelTable.setDefaultRenderer(RDFNode.class, new MyRDFNodeRenderer());
```

Then see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer about how to create a simple renderer. Note that `value` will be an `RDFNode`:

```
static class MyRDFNodeRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public MyRDFNodeRenderer() { super(); }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        setText((value == null) ? "" : FmtUtils.stringForRDFNode((RDFNode) value));
    }
}
```